# Using RxJs groupBy with objects as keys

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to use `groupBy` with RxJs, and I need to use objects as keys. If I don't and I use, for example, simple strings like this:

```
var types = stream.groupBy(
    function (e) { return e.x; }); //x is a string
```

then everything goes fine and my subscription is called once, and once only, for each different key. But if I try with objects, the subscription is called for each element from `stream`, even if a key happens to be the same as previous ones.

There is of course a problem about object equality, but this is where I get confused because I don't understant how to use the additional arguments for `groupBy`. The latest version of docs says there have a 3rd argument that can be a *comparer*, but it never gets called. Earlier docs talk about a *key serializer* which is a totally different idea, but neither ways work for me.

Looking at Rx source code, I see attempts to check for a `getHashCode` function, but I do not find and documentation about it. Code like this:

```
var types = stream.groupBy(
    function (e) {
        return { x: e.x, y: e.y };   //is this valid at all?
    },
    function (e) { return e; },
    function (...) { return ???; }); //what am I supposed to do here?
```

is what i'm trying to write, but no luck, and whatever I put for the 3rd callback is not called.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to make sure your key function returns a number or string.  But if you really want to return an object as your key, then you can use `comparer` and `hashCode` to help `groupBy`.  Instead of `hashCode` (which requires you return a number), you can use `valueOf` which lets you return a string.

`hashCode` and `valueOf` should work similar to the [c# Object.GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx).

They should return a value such that:

- Two keys that are considered equal should return the same value every time.
- Two keys that are considered not equal should usually return a different value (to minimize collisions).  The better you can ensure this, the more efficient the dictionary will be.

The difference is `hashCode` should return a number and `valueOf` can return a number or a string.  Thus `valueOf` is easier to implement.

The rules for the `comparer` is that it takes 2 key values and should return `true` to indicate equality and `false` to indicate inequality.

So, you might write your example as:

```
var valueOf = function () {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
};

var keyCompare = function (a, b) { return a.x === b.x && a.y === b.y; };

var types = stream.groupBy(
    function (e) {
        return { x: e.x, y: e.y, valueOf: valueOf };   //is this valid at all?
    },
    function (e) { return e; },
    keyCompare);
```

But if your `valueOf` function is actually producing unique values that match your comparer and you don't really care about whether the key is tramsitted downstream as an actual object, then just make your life easier and transform your key into a string and use a string key like so:

```
var types = stream.groupBy(
    function (e) { return JSON.stringify({ x: e.x, y: e.y }); },
    function (e) { return e; });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is the right direction. With the current version of RxJs (2.3.24) it actually does not work, but I think there is a bug in RxJs, with a small fix the valueOf suggestion works fine. I created a pull request for that: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/pull/510

Comment: Pull request just merged, the fix will soon be available to everybody :)