# rxjs groupBy with object as key

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Basically this question: [Using RxJs groupBy with objects as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000305/using-rxjs-groupby-with-objects-as-keys), but 5 years later.

How can I use rxjs (6) groupBy operator with an object as a key.

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-groupby-key-vals-tldfyu?file=index.ts for a (not) working example.

```
const people = [
   { date: {year: 2000, month: 1, day: 1}, name: 'Sue', age: 25 },
  { date: {year: 2000, month: 1, day: 2},name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
  {date: {year: 2000, month: 1, day: 2}, name: 'Frank', age: 25 },
  { date: {year: 2000, month: 1, day: 3},name: 'Sarah', age: 35 }
];

from(people).pipe(
  groupBy(person => person.date),
  mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

I understand that rxjs uses equality and that just doesn't work with objects.
The solution suggested in the linked question was to use the keyComparer property of the groupBy function. However five years later the keyComparer property doesn't exists anymore.

Because I want to format the date later in the view layer and not in the data layer I want to include the full date object and not an already formatted date.

So what are my options?

Comment: Have you considered stringifying the date (`groupBy(person => JSON.stringify(person.date)...`)? You'll get a key easily deconstructible back to the original value.

Comment: Yes but then I have to reconstruct it in the view layer. While this will definitly work it just doesn't seem right and the keySelector from 5 years ago seems just right for exatcly this problem.

Comment: Well, I actually meant keyComparer instead of keySelector.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-groupby-key-vals-qb9rcb) suit your need?

Comment: No not really because I also have to unserialize the date in the view layer too. But I have come come to the conclusing that this is just not possible anymore with plain rxjs. I decided to use rxjs just for reactive behaviour and use plain functions that work on arrays for the business logic. This is also more portable if I decide to not use rxjs one day.

Comment: Well, the result in that last example actually isn't serialized; all emitted arrays have dates in the same format as in the oriiginal dataset. But your approach has some merits; from my experience RxJS mostly fits when dealing with 'streaming' data.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the `groupBy` for each of the parameters in the object you need to group by:
see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-groupby-key-vals-taa4wf?file=index.ts) forked from your example.

```
from(people)
  .pipe(
    groupBy(person => person.date.year),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
    // Take each from above array and group each array by month
    mergeMap(array => {
      return from(array).pipe(
        groupBy(person => person.date.month),
        mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
      );
    }),
    mergeMap(array => {
      return from(array).pipe(
        groupBy(person => person.date.day),
        mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Though it's a possible solution, I don't know if it's worth the hassle of doing that with rxjs, so that is also something you should consider